# Запуск скрипта в Editor Unity

Tags: unity3d, unity3d-editor

Как можно сделать скрипт,который будет работать в редакторе Unity.Нужно для:
[image]
 К мешу прикреплены 3-сферы,которые задают vertices Меша,как мне можно изменять положение сфер в редакторе?
Пробовал:[ExecuteInEditMode] - он работает так-же как и обычный скрипт в воспроизведении.
Подскажите,есть еще способы вызова функций в редакторе?(нужно для перемещения сфер и создания mesh-a сразу в редакторе)
Желательно,чтоб можно было отследить,Скрипт работает в редакторе,или в воспроизведении(для отключения ненужных поисков сфер треугольниками)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Возможно, вам поможет [MenuItem](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/MenuItem.html). Он позволяет запускать метод любым удобным способом из редактора, хоть с помощью горячих клавиш.
Для проверки "а не в редакторе ли я" можно использовать свойство Application.isEditor. Оно как раз возвращает "а не в редакторе ли вы" :)

Answer (score 0):

Тем,кто наткнется на эту тему: Решил вопрос custom editor,он как-раз для этого оказывался и предназначен,пришлось правда пару скриптов переписать,но зато дальнейшее удобство в разы повышается